# Angular POST request sending info in parameters that I did not specify and Rails throwing errors about it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So I am currently making a user create a new account on a Rails app using devise.

The registration is handled by Angular on the client side.

Here is the angular code for it:

```
This method is in a controller

$scope.create = (isValid) ->
            $scope.submitted = true
            if isValid
                UserService.create_user(user: {
                    name: $scope.name,
                    email: $scope.email,
                    password: $scope.password,
                    password_confirmation: $scope.password_confirmation
                }, submit: 'Sign up', (response)->
                    console.log(response)
                )
                console.log(isValid)
                #@userService.createUser(user, $scope)
            else

@Fit.service 'UserService', [
    '$resource', '$http', '$routeParams', 'Common',
    ($resource, $http, $routeParams, Common) ->
        $resource '/users/:id/:options.json', { id: '@id', options: '@options' },
            create_user: {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            set_avatar: {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            update_user: {
                method: 'PATCH'
            },
            find: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            update_role: {
                method: 'PATCH'
            }

]
```

Now when I send the request on the way I get this in my server log:

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-28 22:45:35 +0300
Value for params[:user][:password] was set to nil, because it was one of [], [null] or [null, null, ...]. Go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#unsafe-query-generation for more information.
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"foo", "email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "submit"=>"Sign up", "registration"=>{"user"=>{"name"=>"foo", "email"=>"foo@bar.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "submit"=>"Sign up"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'foo@bar.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Now there are two things wrong with this log. First of all in the parameters section I have a list of the same values that I put under `user` object also under the `registration` object. Now I have no idea where that came from.

As you can see in the picture, chrome debugger shows that no such params where sent. Only the user one. Yet rails logs show differently.

[image: My request params]

Now the second problem here is that for some reason the log is throwing errors about the params I sent and I also get this response:

```
{"errors":{"password":["can't be blank"],"password_confirmation":["doesn't match Password"]}}
```

What could be causing these issues?
I checked up what is being sent if I use .erb user creation with a new Devise project and there it also sent all the params under the `user` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the `registration` hash, it's possible that Devise is using `wrap_parameters` or similar to copy the entire `user` hash over to a format more useful to it. In a quick Google search I didn't see any evidence of this but notice that the `user` and `registration` hash look exactly the same; that smells like `wrap_parameters` (or similar) to me. I understand this is a relatively common behavior and shouldn't inherently cause Rails any confusion; by default Rails should just ignore params that it doesn't specifically know / care about.

But at any rate, I don't see any error message relating to the presence of the `registration` hash; the only errors I see relate to the contents of the `:password` and `:password_confirmation` field. I'd take those at face value:

- Angular sent `params[:user][:password]` value to an empty array (`[]`); Rails understandably replaces `[]` with `nil`. Can you double-check that Angular is submitting the right `password` value?
- `password` and `password_confirmation` don't match. This is obvious given the above: `password` is interpreted as `nil`, `password_confirmation` is `"foobar"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Clears a lot of confusion.